# Application of Markov/Cauchy Schwarz

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y\ge0$ with $v=\mathbf E(Y^2)<\infty$ then i need to show that $(\mathbf E|Y^2-v|)^2\le4v(v-(\mathbf EY)^2)$. I had tried using Markov Inequality as well as Cauchy Schwarz inequality but failed to tackle with this problem.

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(\mathsf{E}|Y^2-v|)^2\le \mathsf{E}|Y-\sqrt{v}|^2\mathsf{E}|Y+\sqrt{v}|^2=4(v-\sqrt{v}\mathsf{E}Y)(v+\sqrt{v}\mathsf{E}Y)
$$

Comment: Thanks. I had not even thought that it can be made this much easy.